# Passing an argument that could be of multiple types to a method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, types

I am using a library with a method `foo` with a signature like this:

```
TypeR foo(TypeA first, int second)
TypeR foo(TypeB first, int second)
TypeR foo(TypeC first, int second)
```

I am writing my own method `bar` calling `foo`, and I want to directly pass the first parameter along to `foo`:

```
bar(??? first, int baz) {
    int second = someCalculation(baz);
    return foo(first, second);
}
```

My problem is that I do not know what type I should give to the parameter `first` in `bar`. There does not seem to be union typs in Java. How can I solve this without having to write three almost identical versions of `bar`?

The types `TypeA` to `TypeC` do not share a common interface, and I have no control over them or `foo` since they are in an external library. All I can control is how I implement `bar`.

Comment: if TypeA, TypeB, and TypeC all extend a common base class or implement a common interface, then write your method in terms of 'that' type.
Otherwise, you may be able to use a ['Generic Type'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 5):

The closest I can think of is something like this (removing the stuff relating to `second` since it is irrelevant to the point).

```
TypeR bar(Object first) {
  TypeR retvalue;
  if (first instanceof TypeA)
    retvalue = foo( (TypeA)first );
  else if (first instanceof TypeB)
    retvalue = foo( (TypeB)first );
  else if (first instanceof TypeC)
    retvalue = foo( (TypeC)first );
  return retvalue;
}
```

If there is a more specific known supertype of TypeA etc., you could obviously use that instead of `Object` as the parameter.

This is only possible if all three versions of `foo` have the same return type.

Sadly, this "solution" is not really better, and maybe worse, than writing three overloaded versions of `bar`.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in blanket statements of what is "good practice".  If you really think so, perhaps you could explain why.  In any case, I simply posted the only technique I can think of that approaches what the poster is requesting.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment, but I think I possibly didn't explain.  Since the OP didn't specify the return type of the functions, I just used T as a placeholder in my sample code.  In reality I would replace it with `int` or whatever is the appropriate return type.  I didn't mean to imply that the compiler would figure out the return type on its own.

Comment: +1 for both pointing to a solution, and highlighting that overloading might be better. I updated the question to clarify that all versions of `foo` share the same return type.

Comment: @BraulioLopez I would be interested in references for why it's bad practice to use `instanceof`. In the case of working with 3rd party APIs in which you have no control over the class hierarchy, and which were possibly written prior to the advent of generics in Java, using `instanceof` seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Mike because the code will be coupled with the types from the library, then if we want to change the library or test our code it will be difficult to do. For instance, lets think that the types are ways to connect to a remote server and the library provides ssh and ftp connections as `types`. If we want to test this code we will need a real connection to satisfy the types. So I prefer Andrey Tyukin answer that Isolate each type then them can be easily replaced with whatever we could want in the future.

Answer (score 3):

*In theory*, nothing prevents you from using typeclasses for ad-hoc polymorphism in Java:

```
interface Fooable<T> {
    int foo(T t, int second);
}

public int bar<T>(T t, int baz, Fooable<T> fooable) {
    int second = someCalculation(baz);
    return fooable.foo(t, second);
}
```

The implementations would look roughly as follows:

```
public class TypeAFooable implements Fooable<TypeA> {
    public int foo(TypeA t, int second) { return yourLibrary.foo(t, second); }
}
```

And invocations would look like

```
bar(myTypeAThing, 1234, new TypeAFooable());
```

If `bar` were a little bit longer, this would bring several advantages:

- if `bar` makes lots of calls to `foo` in lots of different places, then you could define each instance of the typeclass *once*, instead of having multiple `if-instanceof`-branches inside of `bar`
- if you later want to make it work with `TypeD`, `TypeE`, ..., `TypeZ`, you don't have to dig into code of `bar`, you can simply supply yet another typeclass implementation
- more importantly: if *someone else* wanted to use it with `TypeD`, `TypeE`, etc., then *they* could supply yet another typeclass implementation, without having to fork your `bar` implementation.

In practice, the problem is that the typeclass instances won't be supplied automatically by the compiler, so it's usually not worth the hassle. Unless `bar` is somehow gigantic and super-complex, just overload it, or use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define first as a [generic type](https://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-example-method-class-interface) type in bar as below.

```
bar(Object first, int baz) {
int second = someCalculation(baz);
if(first instanceOf TypeA) return foo((TypeA) first, second);
else if(first instanceOf TypeB) return foo((TypeB) first, second);
else if(first instanceOf TypeC) return foo((TypeC) first, second);
else throw new CustomException("Object pass in is not of correct type");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to avoid this problem by decomposing your `bar()` function into the piece that deals with computing `int second` and the piece that deals with `TypeA`/`B`/`C first`. That way you could write something like

```
int second = decomposedPortion(baz);
TypeR result = foo(first, second);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can replace the call of `foo` in `bar` by a call of a corresponding `BiFunction`. Thus for all overloaded `foo` methods a `BiFunction` has to be defined.

```
  private static final Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<?, Integer, TypeR>> FOO = Map.of(
    TypeA.class, (first, second) -> foo((TypeA) first, second),
    TypeB.class, (first, second) -> foo((TypeB) first, second),
    TypeC.class, (first, second) -> foo((TypeC) first, second));
```

But for every overloaded `foo` mapping one line only has to be written whereas each overloaded `bar` method would need four lines if it were written as like in the question.

Now we can make `bar` generic. But the following will not work, since the returned `BiFunction` has an unbound wildcard as first type parameter.

```
  <T> TypeR bar(T first, int baz) {
    int second = someCalculation(baz);
    return FOO.get(first.getClass()).apply(first, second);
  }
```

We would need to declare `FOO` as `Map<Class<T>, BiFunction<T, Integer, TypeR>>` but that's not possible. To work around this we define a method with a type parameter `T` which is supposed to establish the missing type equality. But that's not for free. It's at the cost of a warning resulting from casting:

```
  private static <T> BiFunction<T, Integer, TypeR> fooOf(Object o) {
    return (BiFunction<T, Integer, TypeR>) FOO.get(o.getClass());
  }
```

Now we can use this method in `bar`:

```
  <T> TypeR bar(T first, int baz) {
    int second = someCalculation(baz);
    return fooOf(first).apply(first, second);
  }
```

This is similar to an `instanceof` approach but displaces the type distinction from the method `bar` to the `Map` `FOO`. If there are other methods than `bar` which also need to call `foo` in a similar way, the type distinction has not be coded again. `FOO` and `fooOf` can be reused. If the library changes and an additional overloaded `TypeR foo(TypeD first, int second)` gets introduced, only `FOO` needs to be updated by adding one additional line.

This approach requires `first` to be not `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Use interfaces like this:

```
interface Type { //...}

class TypeA implements Type { //...}

class TypeB implements Type { //...}

class TypeC implements Type { //...}
```

then you will only need one foo function

`foo(Type first, int second)`

and one bar function

`bar(Type first, int baz)`

Comment: Yes, this would be a good design approach if the poster had the option.  Unfortunately, the question states that the `foo()` methods are in a library.

Comment: They do not implement a common interface, and I have no controls over `typeA` to `typeC` or `foo`.

Comment: how do you decide wich type must be used to call foo?

Comment: I don't understand your question?